# Getting checkbox value in PHP Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I've looked about everywhere and I know that the method I'm using should work, as many others have asked this question and it has worked.

However, for myself, it doesn't seem to want to work.

**The question:** Why does my array only display the last item in the list?

The code:

Form:

```
<form id="searchglue" method="post" action="<?=base_url();?>index.php/main/search">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Amber"                  value="Amber">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Beige"                  value="Beige">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Black"                  value="Black">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Brown"                  value="Brown">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Clear"                  value="Clear">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Cola"                   value="Cola">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Cream"                  value="Cream">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Dark Blue"              value="Dark Blue">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Dark Green"             value="Dark Green">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Glitter Gold"           value="Glitter Gold">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Glitter Green"          value="Glitter Green">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Glitter Multicoloured"  value="Glitter Multicoloured">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Glitter Red"            value="Glitter Red">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Glitter Silver"         value="Glitter Silver">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Gold"                   value="Gold">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Light Blue"             value="Light Blue">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Light Brown"            value="Light Brown">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Light Green"            value="Light Green">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Oak"                    value="Oak">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Orange"                 value="Orange">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Pale Amber"             value="Pale Amber">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Red"                    value="Red">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Silver"                 value="Silver">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="White"                  value="White">
    <input type="checkbox" name="colour[]"  id="Yellow"                 value="Yellow">
</form>
```

Where it ends up:

```
foreach($_POST['colour'] as $r):
    echo $r;
endforeach;
```

I am using `ajax` to get the results which I THINK is where the error is with getting all the `name` attributes, but I don't know what to do with it...

So here is the ajax:

```
$('form#searchglue').on('change', function() {
    var obj = $(this),
    url = obj.attr('action'),
    method = obj.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    obj.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var obj = $(this),
        name = obj.attr('name'),
        value = obj.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#load").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

No matter what I do, whether I tick something, or have them all unticked completely, the result will always be **Yellow** (the last one in the input list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `serialize()` method to get form value

```
$('form#searchglue').on('change', function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    url = obj.attr('action');
    method = obj.attr('method');

    data =obj.serialize(); 

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#load").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Documentation : [**.serialize()**](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me!